# Should I be doing push-ups if I can do dips in order to hit chest muscles?

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, push-ups, chest, dips

I was doing the following exercise https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBJTLMaJZrQ for some weeks. I had been doing just 3 sets of normal push-ups till the fatigue before, so it took only a few weeks for the exercise in order to become easy to me to perform. Now, I can do about 12 reps of dips in a set.

My question is: should I just switch to dips (My priority muscles are chest muscles), or should I perform both dips and that exercise about which i attached the link above?

Comment: Why do you want to switch one for the other? Why not do both?

Comment: If you're training properly. You shouldn't have a "Priority" where you just do either push ups or dips. You should train everything with a balance and incoorporate more than just one exercise.

Comment: Alec, they say dips are like push-ups but you're lifting your bodyweight without help of your legs. Like a harder variation of push-ups. However I don't feel as much chest work when doing dips as I feel when doing push-ups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Push ups**

Although decline pressing increases pectoral activation[(1)](http://suppversity.blogspot.com/2011/07/suppversity-emg-series-musculus.html) so Dips would indeed be better, I believe push ups should be prioritized because they train the abdominal muscles, to a great extent actually since abdominal muscles, specially the obliques work the hardest during exercises that involve resisting the spine from bending backward[(2)](https://www.t-nation.com/training/inside-the-muscles-best-ab-exercises).

And not only that but push ups have a greater range of variations, with dips you can only progress to weighted dips or ring dips, but push ups can be transformed in psuedo-planche push ups, then planche push ups, and one arm or weighted are still an option.

The planche push up might seem like an extreme movement but it doesn't take more 12-15 months for most people and once you learn a planche press you can progress into a maltese pull.